# React js Backend data not fetching

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch-api, react-context

```js
// Get projects for the logged-in student
// -- THIS IS THE API WHERE USER GET'S HIS SUBMITTED PROJECTS
router.get('/my-projects', async (req, res) => {
  const studentId = req.user.id;

  try {
    const projects = await Project.find({ student: studentId });
    res.json({ success: true, projects });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is ProjectState and Context

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const ProjectContext = createContext();

export default ProjectContext;
```

This is where I've created a context

```jsx
// import ProjectContext from './ProjectContext';
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const ProjectContext = createContext();

const ProjectState = (props) => {
  const [projects, setProject] = useState([]);

  // Get all Projects
  const getProject = async () => {
    // API Call
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      console.log("Token:", token); // Log the token to check its value
      if (!token) {
        // Handle token not found case
        alert("Authorization token not found");
        return;
      }
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:5000/project/my-projects`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          Headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            // 'Authorization': `'Bearer ${token}'`
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        },
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      setProject(json);
    } catch (error) {
      alert("Some error occured" + error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ProjectContext.Provider value={{ projects, getProject }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProjectContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default ProjectState;
```

Here I'm getting error It's saying projects cannot be destructed beacuse it is undefined eventhough I've imported projects from ProjectState.js file

```jsx
// I'm geting error at this component
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import ProjectContext from "../context/projects/ProjectContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Student = (props) => {
  let history = useNavigate();

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const { projects, getProject } = useContext(ProjectContext);

  try {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
        getProject();
      } else {
        history("/student");
        alert("no data found");
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SideBar
        title1="Title 1"
        link1=""
        title2="title 2"
        link2="login"
        username={props.username}
      />
      {Array.isArray(projects) && projects.length > 0
        ? projects.map((project) => {
            return project.title;
          })
        : "No project to show"}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Student;
```

In The main App.s file I've wrapped Student Main Component Inside ProjectState becaue above student component is a child of StudentMAin.js

```jsx
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import StudentMain from "./components/StudentMain";
import Alert from "./components/Alert";
import ProjectState from "./components/context/projects/ProjectState.js";
const App = () => {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);
  const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
      msg: message,
      type: type,
    });
    setTimeout(() => setAlert(null), 2000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ProjectState>
        <Alert alert={alert} />
        <StudentMain showAlert={showAlert} />
      </ProjectState>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```js
const { projects, getProject } =  useContext(ProjectContext);
```

This is the part where I'm getting an error

> projects cannot be destructed because it is undefined

Comment: Why are you creating a context twice, once in `ProjectContext.js` and again in `ProjectState.js`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here...

1. You're creating two contexts; one in `ProjectContext.js` which is used in your component and one in `ProjectState.js` which is used to create your provider. The first one is never assigned a value
2. Your default context value is `undefined` so it will always be possible to receive an undefined value from it.

Uncomment this line in `ProjectState.js`...

```js
// import ProjectContext from './ProjectContext';
```

and remove this line

```js
const ProjectContext = createContext();
```

Now you'll only be working with the one context.

In `ProjectContext.js`, define the context with a default value to avoid errors around undefined values.

```js
const ProjectContext = createContext({
  projects: [],
  getProject: () => { /* no-op */ },
});
```